# Deleting a Table in Word via Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, overwrite

I built a program that transfers cells from Excel into a Word Document as a table. But everytime I use my macro, the table gets pasted above the older one(from a macro usage before) and it stays there. Is there a possibility that I can delete or overwrite the older table with an Excel-VBA code
?

I tried finding and deleting it with Excel VBA --> did not work
Tried recording --> did not work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are adding a table rather than selecting the existing one. Assuming your Word doc has one table in it would be:

```
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
Dim xlBook As Workbook
Dim MySht As Worksheet

Set xlBook = ThisWorkbook
Set MySht = xlBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
SavePath = xlBook.Path
FileNm = "My Word Document.docx"

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(SavePath & FileNm)

WordDoc.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Select
WordApp.Selection.TypeText Text:=Sht.Cells(1, 1)

WordDoc.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Select
WordApp.Selection.TypeText Text:=Sht.Cells(1, 2)

'And so on...
```

Comment: Maybe my Question was not very precise, my mistake. So I have a range of cells in excel which i copy and paste into word as a table. And everytime I use the macro, the new table which gets created, is pasted above the old table. And now the question is, is there a possibility to delete or overwrite the old table per excel macro vba, or do I have to delete them everytime by hand.

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't use copy and paste for that reason, I would use TypeText instead. So in my code I've selected row 1, column 1 in the Word Table and then used TypeText to put the value from my worksheet in cell A1. You could use a For Next loop if they were all in the equivalent places in the spreadsheet and Word Doc table